# Determining JSON.Net property mappings based on JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, json.net

Given a JsonSerializerSettings object, a Type, and a System.Reflection.PropertyInfo object, how could I determine:

1) What the JSON property name will be for that property when converted with JSON.Net with the given settings? Given the various rules and attributes that may or not be present on the property or class itself, and the various settings that might be set in the JsonSerializerSettings?

2) How to know if a given "JSON" property name will be mapped to a c# property when deserializing using JSON.Net? And if so, which property?

```
class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("person_id")]
    Guid PersonId { get; set; }  // given property info for this, want to recieve "person_id"

    string FirstName { get; set; } // will this serialize to "firstName"? "FirstName"? depending on the settings?
    string LastName { get; set; } //given the settings, would { "LASTNAME": "Johnson" } be serialized into this property?

    [JsonIgnore]
    string SSN { get; set; } // determine will this property be mapped?
}
```

Note I'm hoping to find a solution where instead of looking at the property attributes myself (too error prone given all possibilities and contract resolvers), I would like determine based on the JsonSerializerSettings what the property mappings are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you need is available from Json.NET's [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm).  The sequence of steps to access it are as follows:

1. Manufacture a `JsonSerializer` from the settings.
2. Get its [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_ContractResolver.htm).
3. Resolve the contract for your `Person` type and cast it to a [`JsonObjectContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract.htm).
4. Find the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) for your property from the [`Properties`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_Properties.htm) list.  All serialization information about that specific property is there.

Thus e.g. you could create the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    static JsonProperty GetProperty(this JsonSerializerSettings settings, Type type, string underlyingName)
    {
        // Use JsonSerializer.Create(settings) instead if your framework ignores the global JsonConvert.DefaultSettings
        var resolver = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).ContractResolver;
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a JSON object", type));
        return contract.Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == underlyingName).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName(this JsonSerializerSettings settings, Type type, string underlyingName)
    {
        var property = settings.GetProperty(type, underlyingName);
        // The property might be null if it is nonpublic and not marked with [JsonProperty]
        return property == null ? null : property.PropertyName;
    }

    public static bool GetIsIgnored(this JsonSerializerSettings settings, Type type, string underlyingName)
    {
        var property = settings.GetProperty(type, underlyingName);
        // The property might be null if it is nonpublic and not marked with [JsonProperty]
        return property == null ? true : property.Ignored;
    }
}
```

Then, if you use the methods as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};

foreach (var property in typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property {0}: Json name = \"{1}\", IsIgnored = {2}", property, settings.GetPropertyName(typeof(Person), property.Name), settings.GetIsIgnored(typeof(Person), property.Name));
}
```

The output will be

```
Property System.Guid PersonId: Json name = "person_id", IsIgnored = False
Property System.String FirstName: Json name = "firstName", IsIgnored = False
Property System.String LastName: Json name = "lastName", IsIgnored = False
Property System.String SSN: Json name = "ssn", IsIgnored = True
```

Notes:

- Json.NET maintains global default `JsonSerializerSettings` that can be accessed via [JsonConvert.DefaultSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm).  This property

  > Gets or sets a function that creates default `JsonSerializerSettings`. Default settings are automatically used by serialization methods on `JsonConvert`, and `ToObject<T> ()` and `FromObject(Object)` on `JToken`. To serialize without using any default settings create a `JsonSerializer` with `Create()`.

  If your framework ignores the global default settings you should replace `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings)` with `JsonSerializer.Create(settings)` in the above methods.
- For improved performance you could manufacture the serializer once and add the extension methods to `JsonSerializer` rather than `JsonSerializerSettings`.  And if you need multiple attributes for a given property you could just fetch the `JsonProperty` and access it directly.
- Json.NET can serialize fields as well as properties so requiring a `PropertyInfo` to be passed to the extension methods might limit access to some necessary serialization information.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FJQYqB).

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly detailed answer.